# How to iterate through a struct as an array in C: Why does this option work the way it does?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I recently came across a way to iterate through structs as if they were an array (as long as the value type is the same in all members of the struct) and it works as I expect it to and want it to. However, I am having trouble understanding *why* it works. Without understanding why it works, I do not feel comfortable using it, so I was hoping the community could help me out. Below is some code.

StructName is a generic name for my struct of many float values, and iterate is a generic function name. Please take note of the marked line as that is where I am confused on it's operation.

```
void iterate(StructName *s){
//some code
float *a;
a = (float*)&*s; //<---This line
//some more code
a++; //gets next struct member
}
```

This works as expected, I am able to iterate through my struct as an array. If I do the following (remove the (float*) from the marked line):

```
void iterate(StructName *s){
//some code
float *a;
a = &*s; //<---This line
//some more code
a++; //gets next struct member
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
warning: assignment to 'float *' from incompatible pointer type 'StructName *' {aka 'struct <anonymous> *'} [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     a = &*s;
```

But the code still compiles and runs as expected.

And then if I do the following (remove the asterisk from the marked line):

```
void iterate(StructName *s){
//some code
float *a;
a = (float*)&s; //<---This line
//some more code
a++; //gets next struct member
}
```

My indexing is largely offset by a seemingly random amount.

Comment: This is  a bad idea in general. It is violating a bunch of C rules, such as strict aliasing,  and making a bunch of assumptions that are not guaranteed by C - such as structure layout.

Comment: Do not do this.  It is undefined behavior.  Take some time to re-think how you are managing your data.

Comment: The third case obviously won't work because you are pointing to the pointer, not pointing to the struct.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The line `a = (float*)&*s;` does several things.

`*s` dereferences the struct. Then `&*s` gets a reference again, so `&*s` is identical to `s` unless `s` is not a valid pointer, in which case the conversion will fail. The point of `&*s` is to make sure the pointer points to a real struct.

Now, `s` is a pointer to the struct, so it basically points to the first element of the struct. We need to cast this to `(float*)` so that the compiler will know what size the pointer is pointing to, and how we want to treat it - so all that line does is get a pointer to the first struct element.

When incrementing `a`, the compiler already knows `a` is a float pointer so it increments `a` by the size of a `float`, thus getting the next element, and so on.
This is why it will only work for structs with the same type of elements (and even that is not guaranteed, as the C standard allows padding between elements).

Your two examples fail because in the first, you don't cast the pointer to a `float*`, which creates an assignment of different types, and in the second, you try to cast a pointer to a pointer to the struct to a pointer, which makes no sense.

This is a fun experiment, however as others have mentioned it is not good practice, and you really shouldn't iterate through structs like that on a regular basis.

Comment: I can confirm that the C standard does state that `*&` does nothing.  There *might* be one exception in the case of an object that is `register` qualified.  I'd have to look that up again.

Comment: Thank you so much! I ended up replacing `a = (float*)&*s` with `a = (float*)s`, which does exactly the same thing. Makes sense, as I'm getting the address of an already dereferenced pointer... Anyways I am now well aware that it is bad practice but this code is in reference to some skeleton code that required using a struct. I would've used an array or enum otherwise.

Comment: "_...it will only work for structs with the same type of elements._" -- not necessarily; note that the Standard allows padding between structure members. This would be unexpected when the members are of the same type, but still allowable.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: It is `&*`, not `*&`, and it does not do nothing; it guarantees that the value it is applied to is a pointer, since, if it were not, there would be a diagnostic due to the constraint violation from applying `*` to something that is not a pointer.

Comment: @exnihilo I also added a note about that.

Answer (score 1):

Iterating through members of a structure is not something that can be done in C.  Attempting to do so invokes undefined behavior.
From section 6.5.6 p8 of the C11 working draft:

> When  an  expression  that  has  integer  type  is  added  to  or  subtracted  from  a  pointer,  the
>   result has the type of the pointer operand.  If the pointer operand points to an element of
>   an array object, and the array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from
>   the original element such that the difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original
>   array elements equals the integer expression.  In other words, if the expression
>   P
>   points to
>   the
>   i
>   -th  element  of  an  array  object,  the  expressions
>   (P)+N
>   (equivalently,
>   N+(P)
>   )  and
>   (P)-N
>   (where
>   N
>   has the value
>   n
>   ) point to, respectively, the
>   i+n
>   -th and
>   i−n
>   -th elements of
>   the  array  object,  provided  they  exist.   Moreover,  if  the  expression
>   P
>   points  to  the  last
>   element of an array object, the expression
>   (P)+1
>   points one past the last element of the
>   array  object,  and  if  the  expression
>   Q
>   points  one  past  the  last  element  of  an  array  object,
>   the  expression
>   (Q)-1
>   points  to  the  last  element  of  the  array  object.  **If  both  the  pointer
>   operand  and  the  result  point  to  elements  of  the  same  array  object,  or  one  past  the  last
>   element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.  If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
>   shall not be used as the operand of a unary
>   *
>   operator that is evaluated.**

(bold emphasis mine)

In this case, taking the address of float member of the array can be treated as an array of size 1.

If you want a data-structure that holds many floats which can be indexed as an array, use an array.  If you have chosen a struct because you want nice readable names such as you get with struct members, you can use `enum`s to index your array with nice readable names.

Here's a simple example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum float_array_enum {FLOAT_X=0, FLOAT_Y, FLOAT_Z, FLOAT_ARR_LENGTH};

int main(void){
   float my_array[FLOAT_ARR_LENGTH] = {0.f};
   for(enum float_array_enum i = FLOAT_X; i < FLOAT_ARR_LENGTH; ++i) {
      my_array[i] = (float) i;
   }
   printf("my_array[FLOAT_X]: %f\n", my_array[FLOAT_X]);
   printf("my_array[FLOAT_Y]: %f\n", my_array[FLOAT_Y]);
   printf("my_array[FLOAT_Z]: %f\n", my_array[FLOAT_Z]);
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: When you say that it can't be done, do you mean it shouldn't be done? As I've outlined this method DOES work, it does exactly what I want it to. I just am having trouble figuring out WHY it works. If you mean the latter, then I will use enums in the future.

Comment: It is undefined behavior.  One of the possible effects of undefined behavior is that it does what you think it will do (until the worst possible moment and then it won't thanks to Murphy's law)

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I would plan to use an array anyways, but this question is in reference to skeleton code that required the use of a struct. If I wrote the code myself, I would absolutely use an array.

Comment: The only legal way to iterate through the contents of a structure is to treat as an array of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @austinhoang: That is correct; this answer, like so many, misstates the rules of C. By and large, the C standard does not say you **cannot** do something, it only says what will happen if you **do** do various things it defines. In other words, it says “If you do X, Y will happen. If you do Z, we do not say what will happen.” You are still permitted to do Z. You can convert a pointer to a structure to a pointer to a `float` and use it, but the C standard does not define the behavior that results.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Great, thank you for the clarification. A similar "we do not say what will happen" is an out of bounds index. Technically compiles but unknown behavior until run time. Would that be correct?

Comment: @austinhoang: Yes. Note that one problem with the way many people treat undefined behavior is it is completely impractical. The C standard defines only a core language that **must** be extended for any practical usefulness beyond text processing and abstract computing. In order to use any Unix or Windows functions, interact with the user with any GUI (Graphic User Interfaces), control any devices, and so on, you must, at the very least, call and link with libraries with behaviors that are “undefined” by the C standard. So it is just impossible to avoid “undefined” behavior.

Comment: @austinhoang: Aside from simply linking to other libraries and such, many C implementations also extended the language in other ways, defining a variety of things that are not defined by the C standard, such as what happens when you convert integers to pointers and vice-versa (needed for writing operating systems code). So statements that you “cannot” do things that are not defined by the standard or blanket prohibitions about avoiding so-called “illegal” (it is not) behavior are excessive.

Comment: @austinhoang: In this particular, accessing structure member in this way should be avoided not because the C standard says it is illegal (it does not) but because nothing defines it for you—not just the C standard but also not your compiler, presumably.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- Those libraries you mention that use undefined behavior do so on the basis of targeting particular platforms with knowledge of details. It is in general a bad idea to write code that trades in UB, especially if one wants portable code. OP said: "_it works as I expect it to_", but this is not a way to know that code is actually working when UB is involved; rather, compiler documentation and platform details are required.

Comment: @exnihilo: No, it is not in general a bad idea to write code that “trades” in “UB”. It is generally **necessary**, as I have explained. The persistent entreaties on Stack Overflow to avoid it are misguided. A good goal is to cleanly design code so the parts that can be reasonably portable are and that parts that are not are not, and there is clarity and separation where reasonable. Instead of that sensible goal, we overwhelmingly see misplaced pronouncements that code is “illegal“ or “cannot” be used. It is false and fails to teach what people need to know about real uses of C.

Comment: @EricPostpischil -- your comments seem too cavalier about UB. Writing the kind of code you talk about requires detailed knowledge that OP and similar learners do not possess; belief that some UB is fine because "my code is working" has led to many security vulnerabilities and other failures. Avoid UB unless you actually know what you are doing and what could go wrong.

Comment: @exnihilo: “Writing the kind of code you talk about requires” reading a manual, the same as standard C code. Want to call a Unix routine? Read the man page. Want to use GCC-specific behaviors? [Read the documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/C-Implementation.html#C-Implementation). What makes the C standard so special that it is a document students can learn and those other documents are not? Re “belief that some UB is fine because ‘my code is working’”: That is a non sequitur. Nothing in my comments suggests anybody ought to rely on code because it appears to work.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Why would anything else make more sense to reference than the C standard when dealing with C code?  Why should we make the assumption that Undefined Behavior is well-defined in some implementation that somebody may-or-may-not be using?  Implementation-defined behavior?  Sure.  But unless given good reason to do otherwise, Undefined Behavior should be treated as incorrect.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: Nobody wrote that you should assume undefined behavior (not Undefined Behavior; it is not a proper noun) is well-defined in some implementation. As for “unless given good reason,” I have given good reason: It is **impossible** to use only strictly conforming C for practical programming other than text processing and abstract computing. All other practical programs **must** use some behavior beyond what the C standard defines. And so students must know that they can go beyond it, and they should learn when it is appropriate to do so. Blanket prohibitions teach bad ideas.